# Default Content Type Attribute value for Page Directive

Tags: asp.net, content-type

if content type of page directive is not mentioned then what will be the default content type for page directive ??

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page" %>
```

in this case what is the value of `ContentType` ??

Comment: What made you tag this as [tag:ajax]??

Comment: actually i am using this page as source for ajax calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is "text/html", as mentioned in the [documentation for ContentType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The HTTP MIME type of the output stream. **The default value is "text/html"**.